# Angular: How to get the scroll position of an element within a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know the scroll position of an element that is within the page. Consider the code below:

```html
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"><div>
<div>
```

How can I know the scroll position of the top of the body div? The header div height is dynamic so I cannot use it for calculations. I would like to find out how for from the top the body div is, or if the div has already scrolled up past the top of the page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Comment: for complex calculation you can use [Intersection_Observer_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)